# How to over flow a list of text widgets in row Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I used this function to return a list of widgets :

```
List<Text> lastMessageWidget(String lastMessage_text) {

List<String> lastMessage_words = lastMessage_text.split(' ');

List<Text> textWidgets = [];

for (int i = 0; i < lastMessage_words.length; i++) {
  if (lastMessage_words[i].contains(searchText) && searchText !="") {
    Text highlight = Text(
      lastMessage_words[i] + ' ',
      maxLines: 1,
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      softWrap: false,
      style: TextStyle(
        color: fontColor,
        backgroundColor:Colors.pinkAccent.withOpacity(.3),
        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
      ),
    );
    textWidgets.add(highlight);
  } else {
    Text normal = Text(
      lastMessage_words[i] + ' ',
      maxLines: 1,
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      softWrap: false,
      style: TextStyle(
        color: fontColor,
      ),
    );
    textWidgets.add(normal);
  }
}

return textWidgets;
```

}

And I wrapped it in a Row :

```
Row( children: lastMessageWidget(chats_list[position].lastMessage.content),)
```

It caused this a RenderFlex overflow like what shown in this pic below :

[image]

I want to apply TextOverflow.ellipsis to this, I spent a long while searching and thinking and unfortunately I came to nothing at the end so I hope you could help me out.

Comment: You need to constrain your Text widget for TextOverflow to work. Ex: setting a fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

first, for the text widget you need to wrap with Expanded.

secondly, Text overflow like this:

```
Text(
      'Text largeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee',
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
```

Answer (score 0):

You need set Text widget width or limit its width.

```
Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                  child: Text(
                'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                maxLines: 1,
              )),
              Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Text(
                    'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb',
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                    maxLines: 1,
                  )),
              Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Text(
                    'cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc',
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow),
                    maxLines: 1,
                  )),
              Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Text(
                    'ddddddddddddddddddddddddd',
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                    maxLines: 1,
                  )),

            ],

          )
```

Comment: I used a list of text widgets and text is added to it programmatically, so your solution is not for my case